# Calculate Total hours from each in and out times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a punching application, where each check in(Entry) and check outs(Exit) are recorded in below format.

I have to calculate the total hours stayed inside for each check in and out and for overall Total Hrs Inside

Date format is **YearMonthDate**
Time format is **HourMinuteSecond**

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I am unable to try. This problem is very peculiar for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your table to have enter and exit rows as columns. after that you will have to use following queries:

```
SELECT Date, TimeInput, TimeOutput, DATEDIFF(hours,TimeInput,TimeOutput) AS HoursInside
FROM yourTableName
```

to calculte total hours:

```
select Date, SUM(HoursInside) as TotalHours
FROM yourTableName 
Group BY Date
```

Comment: Can I create a trigger to get data from one table to another table with modified values(as like your data). Because in old table I dont have write permission

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi i doubt you can modify table by adding trigger if you dont have even write permissions. You can create stored procedure and emplement all business logic there.